# Issues with Cancan and rails_admin with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have setup rails_admin with devise and cancan, I have it so that only admins can access the /admin pages.

But when trying to only show certain code to admins using `<% if user_admin? %>` I get `undefined method`user_admin?' for`

**ability.rb**

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

```
  def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
        can :access, :rails_admin #grant access to rails_admin
        can :dashboard #gives access to the dashboard

      else
        can :read, :all
      end
  end
end
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
 <% if user_admin? %>
 <li><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
 <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
 <% else %>
 <li><%= link_to "Create Account", new_user_registration_path %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: More code would be helpful. The user_admin? method and the show method. You checked https://github.com/ryanb/cancan already? Regards

Comment: I guess I have not finished setting everything up, I figured because if user.admin? worked in the ability.rb file, I could then use the line in other parts of the application to define if user_admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the abilities up in the ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
        can :access, :rails_admin #grant access to rails_admin
        can :dashboard #gives access to the dashboard

      else
        can :read, :all
      end
  end
end
```

Then was able to just call

```
  <% if can? :access, :rails_admin %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Admin', rails_admin_path %></li>
  <% end %>
```

I can now do if can? on anything I want to authorize.